# Add custom template to admin product price tab

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I add additional template file on the admin product price tab? I tried with this, but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
   <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_price>
      <block template="mymodule/additionalinfo.phml"/>
   </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_price>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to reference price tab in xml layout file. But you can do this with a little javascript code. Here is the way:

First, your xml layout should be like this:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="addition_info" template="mymodule/additionalinfo.phml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

Then your `mymodule/additionalinfo.phml` content should be like this:

```
<div id="mycontent" style="display: none">Your content want to display here </div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        var content = $('mycontent').innerHTML;
        $('price').up('table').insert({before: content});
        $('myconent').remove();
    });
</script>
```

If you want content display at bottom, change the line:

```
$('price').up('table').insert({before: content});
```

to

```
$('price').up('table').insert({after: content});
```